# How do I treat my leg after a painful thigh kick?

Tags: injury, kickboxing

I was sparring and received a pretty hard thigh kick. I have been in a tremendous amount of pain since it happened three days ago. I usually bruise easily but there isn't an bruising yet. The pain feels deep and the leg is tight. I can barely put weight on it or bend it. I've been putting ice on it and taking ibuprofen. Does anyone have more suggestions, I'm getting married tomorrow, I want to be able to walk!

Comment: You should go see a doctor. I don't think anyone here should be trying to diagnose and treat your injured leg on this site.

Answer (score 5):

See a doctor.

They may give you stronger pain killer and/or muscle relaxants than you can get OTC, both of which will help you to stop stressing the leg and heal faster.

Aside from that stay off it as much as possible (you can walk down the aisle), go easy, keep up the ice until the swelling recedes then switch to mild heat.

---

I didn't at first but instead kept training on it. Stupid. I was out for six weeks after the leg actual gave out just walking down the hall.

Comment: +1 for the first three words.  No need to read the rest... ^_~